# O que é e e qual a vantagem de usar "span<T>"?

Tags: c++, c++20, gsl

O C++20 conta com um novo tipo [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). Bibliotecas externas como [GSL](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) também provêm implementações compatíveis com C++14 e C++17.

Buscando entender o que é um `span<T>`, esbarrei com a seguinte definição: Um *span* é uma *view* representando uma sequência de elementos contíguos em memória. Essa é uma definição bastante abstrata e, ao menos para um leigo em C++, ela não ajuda muito a entender o que é um `span<T>`.

Tentando entender melhor para que serve um `span<T>` encontrei informações sobre alguns casos de uso recomendados:

### 1. Diretrizes Centrais do C++

Nas [Diretrizes Centrais do C++](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i13-do-not-pass-an-array-as-a-single-pointer**) `span<T>` é mencionado várias vezes em regras como:

#### I.13: Não passe *arrays* como ponteiros:

Errado:

```
void copy_n(const T* p, T* q, int n); // copy from [p:p+n) to [q:q+n)
```

Correto:

```
void copy(span<const T> r, span<T> r2); // copy r to r2
```

#### R.14: Evite parâmetros do tipo`[]`, prefira `span`

Errado:

```
void f(int[]);
```

Correto:

```
void f(gsl::span<int>);
```

### 2. Alternativa para parâmetros do tipo `std::array` e `std::vector`

Além de *C-style arrays*, econtrei exemplos em que `std::array` e `std::vector` são passados como argumentos para funções com parâmetros do tipo `std::span`.

Exemplo do site [Modernes C++](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-std-span):

```
void printMe(std::span<int> container) 
{
    std::cout << "container.size(): " << container.size() << '\n';
    for(auto e : container) std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main() 
{   
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    int arr[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    printMe(arr);
    
    std::vector vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printMe(vec);

    std::array arr2{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
    printMe(arr2);
}
```

Mas afinal de contas o que é o um `span<T>`? Por que devo preferir usar `span<T>` no lugar de um ponteiro, referência para *container* (e.g., `std::vector<int>& refToVector`) ou [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)?

Comment: Parte da minha iniciativa para criar mais perguntas para a comunidade. Fique a vontade para responder essa pergunta (não devo responder essa pergunta a não ser que a pergunta fique aberta sem uma resposta válida por um longo tempo).

Answer (score 4):

> Qual a vantagem de usar "span"?

Principalmente, um pouco mais de segurança (principalmente quando aliado à análise estática) e, por vezes, conveniência.

---

Uma breve definição para `span<T>`:

- É uma abstração que fornece uma *view* sobre uma sequência de dados do tipo `T` em algum lugar na memória. Note que o termo ”*view*” é importante, uma vez que indica o fato de que um *span* apenas ”olha” aos objetos, mas não é dono deles ou sequer os gerencia. É bastante simples e quase sem custo.
- Um *span* não é a *sequência* em si, mas sim uma estrutura que contém um ponteiro ao valor `T` inicial e o comprimento dessa sequência, isto é, `{ T *ptr; std::size_t length; }`.

Veja então que, basicamente, um *span* é uma simples abstração que conhece um ponto inicial de memória e um comprimento, que define os seus limites.

Esse “comprimento” é essencial para a garantia de que, usando um *span*, você não vai acessar objetos além de seu alcance. Isso torna o programa mais confiável e seguro.

Um `span<T>` pode ser estático ou dinâmico. Estático no sentido de que o seu comprimento é conhecido pelo compilador – em casos como esse o *span* nem precisa sequer ter o campo `length` (fica ainda mais barato!). Nesses casos, também há uma série de garantias que podem ser feitas estaticamente, de modo que acessar um valor fora dos limites do *span* é um claro erro que impede a compilação do programa.

Claro que as mesmas garantias de segurança ao tentar acessar valores fora do limite também se aplicam a *spans* dinâmicos, mas nesse caso as verificações são obviamente feitas em *runtime*.

Esse tipo de garantia, sem dúvidas, leva a programas de maior qualidade. Compare um `span<T>` com o famigerado par `(T*, length)` – nesse último caso *nada* impede o programador de acessar um valor que ultrapasse os limites estipulados por `length`.

Além disso, não se pode deixar de elencar certo ganho maior possibilidades de modularização, composição e reuso de código. Isso fica evidente no próprio código da pergunta.

Veja que um `span<T>` pode ser trivialmente construído a partir de *C-style arrays*, `std::array`s `std::vector`s e outros contêineres. Como o *span* não representa o *mecanismo* de armazenamento e gerenciamento dos dados, mas sim apenas uma *visualização* sobre eles, fica muito fácil de utilizá-lo para representar a sequência de dados de diversos contêineres (como os próprios `std::array` ou `std::vector`).

---

> Por que devo preferir usar `span<T>` no lugar de um ponteiro?

Só o ponteiro não. São coisas diferentes.

Mas o idioma ponteiro *e* comprimento é encorajado “inseguro” se comparado ao `span<T>`. Não há nenhuma garantia de que o comprimento passado junto ao ponteiro de fato será usado como limite. O *span* garante que essa invariante seja cumprida.

Em código novo é indicado utilizar um *span* ao invés do par ponteiro-comprimento para representar uma sequência contínua de objetos.

> Por que devo preferir usar `span<T>` no lugar de uma referência para contêiner?

Porque ele é mais genérico e barato, mas de modo geral é importante compreender as diferenças.

O *span* fornece acesso aos elementos da sequência ao qual ele visualiza. Também permite a modificação *desses* elementos (assumindo que seja um `span<T>` e não um `span<const T>`, por exemplo).

Contudo, o *span* não permite modificar o tamanho da sequência ao qual ele enxerga. Adicionar um novo elemento à sequência, por exemplo, não pode ser feito com *span*. Nesse tipo de situação, obviamente, não é possível receber um *span*, mas sim uma referência à contêiner que permita modificação de seu tamanho, como o próprio `std::vector`. Vai de caso a caso.

De modo geral, quando só se quer mexer nos dados de uma sequência específica (incluindo de modo genérico entre vários tipos de contêineres), *span* pode ser bastante útil.

> Por que devo preferir usar `span<T>` no lugar de um iterador?

Um *span* não é conceitualmente o mesmo que um iterador. Um iterador é uma abstração para *iterar* sobre valores. Um *span* é abstração sobre a visualização de uma sequência contínua de dados. Há, contudo, a possibilidade de se criar um iterador a partir de um *span*. A recíproca não é necessariamente verdadeira.

---

Algumas observações importantes a serem feitas:

1. É crucial ressaltar o fato de que o *span* não é dono de nada. Ele apenas fornece uma visão a dados que pertencem a outro objeto (como um `std::array`). Os elementos dentro dos limites estipulados, todavia, ficam acessíveis pelo *span* que, por exemplo, faz *overload* do `operator[]` para o acesso dos elementos.
2. `span<T>` foi projetado para ser barato para ser construído, copiado, movido e usado. Os usuários são encorajados a utilizá-lo com semântica de *valor*.
3. Todos os acessos aos dados dentro dos limites do *span* são conceitualmente *range-checked* de modo a garantir que continuem dentro dos *span bounds*. Portanto, desde que uma sequência seja acessada por um *span* corretamente inicializado, é garantido que seus limites não podem ser violados.

   - Nesse sentido, em implementações de referência, por exemplo, ao violar um *range-check*, chama-se `terminate()`, mas a implementação pode optar por continuar a execução com *undefined behavior*. Nesse caso, obviamente, considera-se fatal a capacidade do programa continuar uma execução confiável.
4. O *span* é esperado ser utilizado em situações onde anteriormente se utilizava o par ponteiro-comprimento. É um “substituto seguro” para esse tipo de idioma. É, nesse sentido, extremamente encorajado.
5. Para simplificar a passagem por parâmetros, `span<T>` fornece vários construtores para contêineres comumente utilizados para armazenar sequências contínuas de elementos (como `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc). Isso foi demonstrado em um dos excertos de código da própria pergunta. O *span* é bastante genérico nesse sentido.

---

Não teria sido capaz de escrever esta resposta sem estas publicações. Me baseei fortemente em:

- [span: bounds-safe views for sequences of objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf)
- [What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/7445826)